# How can i take the title of the button i click on and use it as an H1 for the page with my code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

So I'm writing a react app, and I created the side bar in this way:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { NavbarData } from "./NavbarData";
import { IconContext } from "react-icons";
import "./Navbar.css";
import Hamburger from "./Icons/Hamburger.svg";
import closeIcon from "./Icons/Close.svg";
import "./Icons/p_logo_color.png";

function Navbar() {
  const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(false);
  const showSidebar = () => setSidebar(!sidebar);
  var pageName = ;

  return (
    <>
      <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: "undefined" }}>
        <div className="navbar">
          <Link to="#" className="menu-bars">
             <img src={Hamburger} alt="" onClick={showSidebar} />
          </Link>
          <div className="pageTitle"><h1>{pageName}</h1></div>
        </div>
        <nav className={sidebar ? "nav-menu active" : "nav-menu"}>
          <ul className="nav-menu-items" onClick={showSidebar}>
            <li className="navbar-toggle">
              <Link to="#" className="menu-bars">
              <img src={closeIcon} alt=''/>
              </Link>
            </li>
            {NavbarData.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <li key={index} className={item.cName}>
                  <Link to={item.path}>
                    <span className="navbutton-text" ><span className="navbutton-icon">{item.icon}</span>{item.title}</span>
                  </Link>
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </IconContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

`NavbarData` looks like this:

```
import React from 'react'

import * as IoIcons from 'react-icons/io';
import settingsIcon from './Icons/Settings.svg';
import startpageIcon from './Icons/startpage.svg';
import performanceIcon from './Icons/Persona.svg';

export const NavbarData = [
    {
        title: 'Monitoring Overview',
        path: '/monitoringoverview',
        icon: <img src={startpageIcon} alt="" />,
        cName: 'nav-text'
    },
    {
        title: "Performance Quality",
        path: "/performancequality",
        icon: <img src={performanceIcon} alt="" />,
        cName: 'nav-text'
    },
    {
        title: "Finance",
        path: "/finance",
        icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />,
        cName: 'nav-text'
    },
    {
        title: "Fraud and Anomalies",
        path: "/fraudandanomalies",
        icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />,
        cName: 'nav-text'
    },
    {
        title: "Simulation",
        path: "/simulation",
        icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />,
        cName: 'nav-text'
    },
    {
        title: "Planning",
        path: "/planning",
        icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />,
        cName: 'nav-text'
    },
    {
        title: "Settings",
        path: "/settings",
        icon: <img src={settingsIcon} alt="" />,
        cName: 'nav-text'
    },
]
```

I'm trying to make a `h1` that changes according to the path I'm in right now. In the `NavbarData` each path is associated with a different item and they also have a title. I want to take that title and put it in `h1` in the `Navbar-topbar` section.

I tried injecting `this.item.title` and to make a function that takes the title of the clicked navbar button and updates the `h1` to no avail.

Comment: You could use `react-router`'s `useLocation()` hook to figure out where you are and find the relevant menu item.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'useLocation' hook to get url and 'useEffect' hook to listen changes in url.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"; // useEffect added
import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom"; // useLocation added
import { NavbarData } from "./NavbarData";
import { IconContext } from "react-icons";
import "./Navbar.css";
import Hamburger from "./Icons/Hamburger.svg";
import closeIcon from "./Icons/Close.svg";
import "./Icons/p_logo_color.png";

function Navbar() {
  const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(false);
  const showSidebar = () => setSidebar(!sidebar);
  const [pageName, setPageName] = useState('Initial Value'); // pageName defined with useState hook to re-render on changes.

  const location = useLocation(); // useLocation hook to get path name

  // useEffect hook to listen changes in location
  useEffect(() => {
    if (location.pathname) {
       getPageTitleByUrl(location.pathname);
    }
  }, [location]);
 

  const getPageTitleByUrl = (path) => {
    // In this function we filter our NavbarData array to find match on path name
    NavbarData.filter((navItem) => {
      if (navItem.path === path) {
         // When our path name equal to path we defined on NavbarData array; we will setPageName with that objects title. 
         setPageName(navItem.title);
      }
    })
  };


  return (
    <>
      <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: "undefined" }}>
        <div className="navbar">
          <Link to="#" className="menu-bars">
             <img src={Hamburger} alt="" onClick={showSidebar} />
          </Link>
          <div className="pageTitle"><h1>{pageName}</h1></div>

        </div>
        <nav className={sidebar ? "nav-menu active" : "nav-menu"}>
          <ul className="nav-menu-items" onClick={showSidebar}>
            <li className="navbar-toggle">
              <Link to="#" className="menu-bars">
              <img src={closeIcon} alt=''/>
              </Link>
            </li>
            {NavbarData.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <li key={index} className={item.cName}>
                  <Link to={item.path}>
        
                    <span className="navbutton-text" ><span className="navbutton-icon">{item.icon}</span>{item.title}</span>
                    
                    
                  </Link>
                  
                </li>
                
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </IconContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

For more information you can look into official React documentation about;

1. [useState](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState)
2. [useEffect](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect)

Comment: Thank you very musch!!! ill be sure to look into it

Comment: Hey so it works but when i refresh the page, the title switches back to the default one, while the path stays the same , do you have an idea how to fix this? so that if i refresh on a certain path the title is kept as it was changed on click.

Comment: I updated the code you can check it out. I misunderstand the situation at the first time, sorry for that.